# NSButton with round corners and background color

Tags: swift, macos

I want a simple push button (the one with the round corners), and to add background to it.
I've tried 2 things:

1 - using a round button image: this is working good, until I need to scale the button, which cause the round parts to look ugly.

2 - extending the button and add color to it - but then I have trouble when I click the button - I want the "pushed" state to be at the same color as the "regular" state, but it's not the case.

this is the code I'm using to extend the button:

```
 override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect)
    {
        if let bgColor = bgColor {
            self.layer?.cornerRadius = 4
            self.layer?.masksToBounds = true
            self.layer?.backgroundColor = bgColor.CGColor
            bgColor.setFill()

            NSRectFill(dirtyRect)
        }

        super.drawRect(dirtyRect)
    }
```

Anyway, neither approach 1 nor 2 worked, so how can I achieve this ? 
Just a simple button..  :(

EDIT:
I'm asking about OSX

Comment: Do you want to change size or color when the button is pressed? Like this? - http://www.gifmania.co.uk/Web-Design-Animated-Gifs/Animated-Web-Buttons/Green-Web-Buttons/Green-Rounded-Button-90785.gif

Comment: I want to have a NSButton with regular behavior, but with background color and rounded corners.

Answer (score 6):

I made a button and succeeded. It looks like this:

[image]

Code:

```
override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    super.draw(dirtyRect)
    // Drawing code here.
    if let bgColor = bgColor {
        self.layer?.cornerRadius = 4
        self.layer?.masksToBounds = true
        self.layer?.backgroundColor = bgColor.cgColor
        bgColor.setFill()
        NSRectFill(dirtyRect)
    }
}
```

drawRect is replaced by draw, and CGColor is replaced by cgColor. The difference between yours and mine is the order. You called `super.draw(dirtyRect)` as last, and I called it first. Maybe your button looks like this:

[image]

I hope this can solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, but as some other solutions here, it has a problem with the title

Comment: Yeah, I thought you just showed a part of your code, and your code could show the title well. Add the `self.title.draw(...)` at the end of this function, the title will appear.

Answer (score 5):

Override NSButtonCell's drawWithFrame method:

```
func drawWithFrame(cellFrame: NSRect, inView controlView: NSView) {
    var border = NSBezierPath(roundedRect: NSInsetRect(cellFrame, 0.5, 0.5), xRadius: 3, yRadius: 3)
    NSColor.greenColor().set()
    border.fill()

    var style = NSParagraphStyle.defaultParagraphStyle()
    style.alignment = NSCenterTextAlignment
    var attr = [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : style, NSForegroundColorAttributeName : NSColor.whiteColor()]

    self.title.drawInRect(cellFrame, withAttributes: attr)
}
```

Comment: The result is the same as override NSButton drawRect

Comment: The button loses it's title

Comment: Thanks, the result isn't looking so good, but since you are the only one who answered about OSX, I'll give the bounty to you

Answer (score 2):

OBJECTIVE-C solution (might help some guys stumble upon this thread)

This sublass extends IB - so you can IB control either:

- Background Color
- Background Color on Hover
- Title Color
- Title Color on Hover
- Corner Radius

It also includes a little alpha animation on hover.

[New controls in IB (click to see screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srFIf.png)

```
//
//  SHFlatButton.h
//
//  Created by SH on 03.12.16.
//  Copyright © 2016 SH. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface SHFlatButton : NSButton

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBInspectable NSColor *BGColor;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBInspectable NSColor *TextColor;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBInspectable NSColor *BGColorHover;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBInspectable NSColor *TextColorHover;
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable CGFloat CornerRadius;
@property (strong) NSCursor *cursor;

@end
```

And the implementation...

```
//
//  SHFlatButton.m
//
//  Created by SH on 03.12.16.
//  Copyright © 2016 SH. All rights reserved.
//

#import "SHFlatButton.h"

@implementation SHFlatButton

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    if (self.TextColor)
        [self setAttributedTitle:[self textColor:self.TextColor]];

    if (self.CornerRadius)
    {
        [self setWantsLayer:YES];
        self.layer.masksToBounds = TRUE;
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.CornerRadius;
    }
}


- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    if (self.BGColor)
    {
        [self.BGColor setFill];
        NSRectFill(dirtyRect);
    }

    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
}


- (void)resetCursorRects
{
    if (self.cursor) {
        [self addCursorRect:[self bounds] cursor: self.cursor];
    } else {
        [super resetCursorRects];
    }
}


- (void)updateTrackingAreas {

    NSTrackingArea* trackingArea = [[NSTrackingArea alloc]
                                    initWithRect:[self bounds]
                                    options:NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingActiveAlways
                                    owner:self userInfo:nil];
    [self addTrackingArea:trackingArea];
}


- (void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)theEvent{
    if ([self isEnabled]) {

        [[self animator]setAlphaValue:0.9];
        if (self.BGColorHover)
            [[self cell] setBackgroundColor:self.BGColorHover];
        if (self.TextColorHover)
            [self setAttributedTitle:[self textColor:self.TextColorHover]];
    }


}

- (void)mouseExited:(NSEvent *)theEvent{
    if ([self isEnabled]) {
        [[self animator]setAlphaValue:1];
        if (self.BGColor)
            [[self cell] setBackgroundColor:self.BGColor];
        if (self.TextColor)
            [self setAttributedTitle:[self textColor:self.TextColor]];
    }
}

- (NSAttributedString*)textColor:(NSColor*)color
{
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    [style setAlignment:NSCenterTextAlignment];
    NSDictionary *attrsDictionary  = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                      color, NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                      self.font, NSFontAttributeName,
                                      style, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, nil];
    NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:self.title attributes:attrsDictionary];
    return attrString;
}
```

EDIT: Button **MUST** have border disabled!

Answer (score 0):

**just try to add this two lines of code into your function.I think you are  getting problem in border width.**

override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect)

```
{
    if let bgColor = bgColor {
        self.layer?.cornerRadius = 4
        self.layer?.masksToBounds = true
        self.layer?.backgroundColor = bgColor.CGColor
        self.layer?.borderColor = UIColor.blackcolor()
        self.layer?.borderWidth = 2.0

        bgColor.setFill()

        NSRectFill(dirtyRect)
    }

    super.drawRect(dirtyRect)
}
```

Comment: Didn't make the difference.

Answer (score -2):

You need to override function layoutSubviews,i.e.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height/2
    self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    self.layer.borderWidth = 2
}
```

I have committed a sample project [here](https://github.com/Rokimkar/CustomButton). All your related code has been written in button.swift and it is in swift 3. Also, I have not set the background image for the button, I am leaving that task up to you.

**P.S.: The answer below is for UIButton, not NSButton. Probably some of it will be valid, probably not everything...**

Comment: Thanks, but I asked about NSButton in OS X, not iOS button on iOS

Answer (score -3):

[image]If you want a button to be rounded, open up your main.storyboard, click on the button and the click on "Show the identity inspector". Under "User defined runtime attributes click on the little + sign twice. And change the code to look like this[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I asked about NSButton in OS X, not UIButton on iOS

Comment: Even if it did, I want to change the button's background color

Comment: You an also change the background color under the Attributes inspector when your button is selected

Comment: Again, you are talking about UIButton. Those fields aren't exists on NSButton

Answer (score -3):

Here's what works for me (**Swift 4**).

To set background color:

```
 myButton.layer?.backgroundColor = CGColor.customSilver
```

To set corner radius:

```
myButton.layer?.cornerRadius = 3
```

Answer (score -5):

Simple 3 line function.

```
@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

func setButton(color: UIColor, title: String)  {
    button.backgroundColor = color
    button.setTitle(title, forState: .Normal)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
}
```

and call it like such

```
 setButton(UIColor.redColor(), title: "Hello")
```

Comment: Thanks, but I asked about NSButton in OS X, not iOS button on iOS